# How to connect to AWS windows server without rdp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, rdp

I have changed some rdp settings to the windows server. I can see the screenshot but I cannot able to connect to the instance. What are the other methods to connect to the instance? I dont have snapshots. How to fix this?

Comment: Thank you, I have reopened the post again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an AMI of your server before doing anything below.

You will not be able to connect to the instance using RDP if you have messed up RDP thru any other tool. You might be able to repair your settings by attaching the root EBS volume on another Windows instance and repairing.

This document will show you how to attach the Windows volume to another server. Just skip the stuff about resetting the password.

[Resetting the Windows Administrator Password](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword_EC2Config.html)

If the changes to RDP were made in the registry, you can also attach the registry on the other Windows instance. Then undo / repair your changes.

Just make sure that you are using the same Windows versions for everything above.

[Load or Unload Registry Hives](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732157(v=ws.11).aspx)

[Edit another Windows install's registry](https://superuser.com/questions/690982/edit-another-windows-installs-registry)

Comment: I'm not technically sound, can we connect the remote computer through cmd or powershell and can make any changes to fix?

Comment: You will need to find someone experienced with Windows systems. The steps are easy but you need to know what you are doing.

Comment: What did you change? Then figure out how to unchange it.